# Usage of youtube API for third party video player

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm looking for an answer from the support team regarding a general question on usage of the API. Am I right to assume that with existence of the API it is legally allowed to stream youtube videos via a third party video player which is operating via the youtube API?

Thanks for your help! Really much appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Patrick

Answer (score 4):

Read the [YouTube terms of service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms), specifically section 4(a)

> You agree not to distribute in any medium any part of the Service or the Content without YouTube's prior written authorization, unless YouTube makes available the means for such distribution through functionality offered by the Service (such as the Embeddable Player).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Somehow I did not find that by checking the terms & conditions